# SpringMVC / HTTP Status 404 – Not Found / The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I want to create a Spring MVC project. When I run the project at tomcat localhost with run configurations ( **http://localhost:8080/springmvc/hello**  or **http://localhost:8080/springmvc**  or **http://localhost:8080/hello**) I got this error:

**HTTP Status 404 – Not Found 

Type Status Report 

Message The requested resource [/springmvc] is not available 

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.50**

What can be the reason of this?
What have done so far is explained below:

I clean the project, delete server configuration and create new, try with tomcat version but not works. How can the problem be solved?

```
>java -version
```

> java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS 
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)

- In the project, JRE setting is like that:

Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> JRE System Library -> JavaSE-1.8

- Eclipse version is :

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.me.spring.springmvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {  
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("hello");
        return modelAndView;
    }   
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.spring.springmvc.controller" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        name="viewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Hello Spring MVC</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet </servlet-class>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello from Spring MVC</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springmvc Maven Webapp</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

- When I click on the start button in Servers / Apache Tomcat server and try to open http://localhost:8080/ to check whether tomcat installation is true or not I got;

[image: tcat]

and in Internal Web Browser(Eclipse)

[image: Internal Web Browser]

- Maven -> Update Project is applied but now works.

**EDIT:**

When I right click on the project, "Run on Server" have not existed; but from there

[https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/download/](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e)

with this link

[download m2e wtp](http://%20http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases)

add in Eclipse -> Install New Software and downloaded m2e wtp, then Run on Server appears now.

When I run project on server,

http://localhost:8080/springmvc/ works as expected but http://localhost:8080/springmvc/hello not works. When this url request is send,

```
...
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Jul 26 17:14:53 EET 2021]; root of context hierarchy
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 881 ms
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springmvc/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved at the end!! When I delete Eclipse cache and change eclipse - workspace , update server configuration, update maven dependencies the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

dude use **jstl.1.2.1.jar** lib for servlet issue